# Changing One Part of Many Fields in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in an SQLite database with a few thousand rows with Name1 and Name2 as two columns.  In many cases Name1 is an LLC or other business and Name2 is the contact person for that corporation.  The entry in the Name2 column often starts with 'C/O' but some start with '%' and others with 'CO' or other abbreviations for 'Care of.'

Is there any way to easily replace just a '%' or 'CO' with 'C/O' without altering the rest of the field?

For instance, if I have these entries:

```
% Grace Hopper
% Charles Babbage
% Fred Astaire
```

I know I can select on just the percent sign (issues with the '%' being used in LIKE aside) and get only those fields starting with it, but is there some way to use a query with an UPDATE to replace just that part of the field and leave the rest alone?  Or to read the rest of the field into a variable and use that in an UPDATE statement?  The result would be:

```
C/O Grace Hopper
C/O Charles Babbage
C/O Fred Astaire
```

I know I can do that with a script in several languages to read the field, edit the string, then use an UPDATE statement, but I'm wondering if there's a SQL way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know how long the prefix you're searching for is, you can just get the rest of the string with `substr()`:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Name2 = 'C/O' || substr(Name2, 2) WHERE Name2 GLOB '%*';
UPDATE MyTable SET Name2 = 'C/O' || substr(Name2, 3) WHERE Name2 GLOB 'CO*';
```

Comment: While I like the other answer, this has the advantage that I won't have to update any fields manually.  I could also GLOB 'CO *' just to be sure it doesn't match a name like 'CORWIN, JOSEPH' and I will know the length of the data I want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has a `replace(haystack, needle, replacement)` function but it will operate on all occurrences in the string, not just the first.

So

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, 'CO', 'C/O') 
   WHERE column LIKE 'CO%' AND NOT LIKE '_%CO%'
```

will get you close for the `CO` update.  You'll then need to look through all records that are still `LIKE 'CO%', if any, and update them manually.

Finding and replacing the `%` case is harder because of course `%` is the "match any" characters in SQL.  You'll need to escape the search term in this case.

Comment: Just to verify - so I'm sure I've got this.  If I do that, and use 'CO%' then it will ONLY get fields starting with CO, so I can limit it with the WHERE clause.  Right?  And, yes, I know I'll have to escape the % - seems like any time you import data, some smart alec entered something that makes even more work, doesn't it?

Comment: If you use `LIKE `CO%` you will find only rows starting with `CO` *but* you will change all occurrences of `CO` in the field so `CO JOE CONWAY` would become `C/O JOE C/ONWAY`.  That's why we leave out records matching `_C/O%` and update them manually.

Comment: Okay - glad I asked and verified that detail!